# byte[] to XImage Fails with Generic GDI+ Error

Tags: .net, image, gdi+, pdfsharp

I'm using PDFsharp to insert an image on a PDF. The image is coming as a binary object from a database. To insert it using PDFsharp, I need to have it as an XImage. Here's what I'm trying so far:

```
XImage sealXImage;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(seal.SealerImage))
// seal.SealerImage is the byte[], I verified this does actually have data in it
{
    Image sealImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    sealXImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(sealImage);
}
 XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(pdfToSeal.Pages[pageNumber]);
 gfx.DrawImage(sealXImage, 425, 475, 150, 100); // generic GDI+ error on this line
```

So it works along merrily until that last line, where a GDI+ error is thrown:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

What have I done wrong and what can I do to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is the `using`: the MemoryStream no longer exists when you call `DrawImage()`. If I'm correct, calling DrawImage inside the `using` block should solve the issue.

You can also invoke `XImage.FromStream()`, but I think you will get the same problem if you do not change the `using` scope.

Comment: Took over an hour of googling and trying things to find this, and was exactly the issue I was having.